# Integral and Summation Exchange

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Why is it possible to do the following?

$\int \space[\space \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n x^n \space]\space dx  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int x^n dx$

I know that this is legal:

$\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n dx  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\int x^n dx$

But I am not sure why the $(-1)^n$ can be taken out seperately.

Comment: Once you accept the second statement you can show the first one, but why is the second statement legal ?

Comment: because you can integrate each term individually

Comment: The $(-1)^n$ can be taken out of the integral because it does not depend on $x$. The interchanging of the integral and summation is the thing you should be more concerned about. In order to interchange infinite summation and integral you need uniform convergence of the function, I don't think you have that here.

Comment: What I am trying to do is represent a functions as a power series,

Comment: The statement which you say is legal is not legal

Comment: why isn't it legal

Comment: You need assumptions on the $f_n$ to justify the exchange; or an invocation of a theorem and explaining why it applies in your case.  Exchanging involves reordering two different limits, which in general changes the answer.

Comment: @theta The question should be why is it legal ? If you have a proof then its legal. If we don't know we should allow for both possiblities (legal or not legal). I said its not legal because I know a counterexample, I will put an answer shortly.

Comment: I made it more specific

Comment: After the changes you made, how can you you use the second statement to deduce the first

Comment: I see it now. I thought $(-1)^n$ wasn't constant because I saw that it changed with the summation(n to inf) but that is irrelevant because IT IS constant within all the integrals in the sum since it is with respect to x

Comment: @Amr out curiosity what is the counter example where it can't be swapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(-1)^n$ is a constant as far as the integral is concerned, since the integral is with respect to $x$, while $(-1)^n$ has no relation to $x$, so it can be factored out.